# handleIntent method is not present in FirebaseMessagingService Class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Messaging Service v 17.3.0, and I want to get data message in logcat when app is in background. As i have seen there was a method called handleIntent in earlier versions to get messages whether app is in background or foreground.

What is the alternative way to handle both Display and Data Messages in newer versions, as onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) method only works when app is in foreground.

And I don't want to downgrade to earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use data payload, then `onMessageReceived` can be called when app is in foreground or background.

So in cloud functions you can use the following:

```
 const payload = {
 data: {
    title:"notification",
    body: "hello world",
    sound: "default"
    },
 };
```

Check this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages